# Spinner is not getting visible

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I have a spinner on which I set the adapter based on a decision during program exection. While it works in one case in the other case the spinner is not visible. Name of the spinner is **sp_term**. Here is the code:

```
            case "830":
                sp_term.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.term830, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                sp_term.setAdapter(adapter);
                Log.e("sp_term 830 ",(sp_term.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) + " " + sp_term.getAdapter());
                break;

            case "836":
                sp_term.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.term836, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                sp_term.setAdapter(adapter);
                Log.e("sp_term 836 ",(sp_term.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) + " " + sp_term.getAdapter());
                break;
```

In case **830** the spinner is visible where as in case **836** the spinner is not visible.

The log record in both cases is as follows:

```
 E/sp_term 830: true android.widget.ArrayAdapter@8038431
 E/sp_term 836: true android.widget.ArrayAdapter@b4bb9b2
```

The array that I'm setting in both the cases are as follows:

```
<string-array name="term830">
    <item>12</item>
    <item>16</item>
    <item>21</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="term836">
    <item>16</item>
    <item>21</item>
    <item>25</item>
</string-array>
```

while in case 830 the spinner gets visible, but in 836 the spinner is not visible. This was working fine earlier. Is there anything else I can check to know the reason.

Can anyone see the cause of problem. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried with `adapter.notifydatasetchanged()`?

Answer (score 0):

The layout width of the spinner in question was set to wrap content, which means its width would adjust according to the width of the adapter content. Though in one case it was displaying, in the other case even after the adapter was being set, it would'nt display. So I finally canged the layout width of the spinner to 0 with layout_weight as 1 and now it displays effectively.